# Get-AzureRmResource returns different data depending on how it was called

Tags: powershell, azure

This just blew my mind.  I run these commands to access a particular resource and print out its location:

```
PS H:\> $hmm = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "RG_NAME" -ResourceName "R_NAME" -ResourceType "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces"
PS H:\> $hmm.Location
East US 2
```

But if I run these commands I get different data for the same field:

```
PS H:\> $hmm2 = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceName -match "R_NAME"}
PS H:\> $hmm2.Location
eastus2
```

Before you ask, I only have one resource whose name is "R_NAME".

Why is the Azure API returning different values depending on how I try to access the data?  Is there some kind of conversion happening in the background on Azure that's normalizing the data or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one except for the devs will be able to answer this question (why this happens exactly). But probably this happens because when you do a get against the subscription you are talking to an Azure Resource provider and when talking to a single resource you are talking to a servicebus provider. And their responses differ. This can happen. Microsoft is a huge company. things like this happen all the time.